# Перенос github репозитория с сохранением форков и тд

Tags: git, github

Как можно перенести репозиторий гит-хаба, например - **в организацию?** или на примере обычного репозитория на другом аккаунте

Сейчас я импортирую текущий репозиторий в новый в новой организции. переносится все, включая коммиты, но **теряются форки, звезды и тд. Можно это как-то исправить** или эта потеря неизбежна?

Comment: Вероятно надо просто клонировать, а потом отредактировать ендпоинт, предварительно экспортировав его туда. Если это сервер, то ендпоинт надо просто удалить. И что значит теряются звёзды? :)

Comment: @NewView вы ни разу не видели звёзд на гитхабе?

Comment: По теме вопроса — у гитхаба в настройках репозитория ведь есть опция переноса

Comment: Вы думаете это как-то связано с гит? Это веб интерфейс, и его фишки на гитхабе, рекомендую почитать про гит, чтобы иметь понимание о том что вы пытаетесь поднять локально. https://git-scm.com

Comment: @NewView в вопросе чётко указано, что речь о гитхабе. Форки и звёзды, которые автор желает сохранить — фичи гитхаба, а не гита. Никто ничего не пытается поднять локально.

Comment: Ну так он никак не сможет сохранить звезды если будет поднимать свой локальный гит.

Comment: @NewView автор не собирается поднимать свой локальный гит

Comment: `перенести репозиторий гит-хаба, например - в организацию?` - а это не локальный гит?

Comment: @NewView нет, организации — это тоже фича сайта github.com

Comment: Из топика автора складывается впечатление что он хочет перенести гит на локальный сервер организации.. :(

Comment: @NewView или наоборот хочет создать организацию на сайте гитхаба. Кто из нас прав или не прав — интересный вопрос, может автор уточнит)

Comment: Да, оставим выбор ему :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всем спасибо!
В настройках репозитория есть опция трансфера!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/309080)

Comment: @Air Вы обращаете внимание только на первое предложение. Между тем, это именно ответ - во втором предложении содержится собственно ответ. Из очереди проверок.

Comment: @AK, ok.  Учту... На будущее